# Adding Name And .. to Phone Book in WPF C #

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner in `WPF` and `C#`. I'm trying to do Phone book Homework. I don't know the syntax to add an Item in a Text File By Each Click. Excuse me because of my question.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.IO.File.CreateText(@"E:\MYText.txt");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string Name01 = NameBox.Text;
        string Name02 =FamilyNameBox.Text;
        string Name03 = PhoneBox.Text;
        string Informtion = Name01 + Name02 + Name03;
        NameBox.Clear();
        FamilyNameBox.Clear();
        PhoneBox.Clear();
        System.IO.StreamWriter MyWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\MYText.txt", true);
        MyWriter.Write(Informtion);
        MyWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: So what happens when you execute this code? Do you get any errors? Does the file exist at the location you have mentioned?

Comment: A google search would have answered this my friend..

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use StreamWriter. Do this instead.

```
List<string> textLines = new List<string>();
string Name01 = NameBox.Text;
string Name02 =FamilyNameBox.Text;
string Name03 = PhoneBox.Text;
string Informtion = Name01 + Name02 + Name03;   
textLines.Add(Information);
// add more lines if you want.
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, textLines);
```

You can also use File.AppendAllLines(fileName, textLines) if you want to append text in other file.

Comment: When I don that its makes the Error :"Use of unassigned local variable textLines "

Comment: you need to do this textLines = new List<string();

Answer (score 0):

I got from one of my apps that writes file, this works 100% adapting to your code

```
using System.IO;//don't forget to reference the IO package
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("class1.txt");
        try
        {
           string Name01 = NameBox.Text;
           string Name02 =FamilyNameBox.Text;
           string Name03 = PhoneBox.Text;
           string Informtion = Name01 + Name02 + Name03;        
           writer.WriteLine(Informtion);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: when I implement this code "Error: The name 'writer' does not exist in the current context" appear!